# What does forward rotation of armature mean?

Tags: motor, universal-motor

Does forward rotation of motor mean clockwise or anticlockwise?

Comment: use the rear-view for forward time  as in clockwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking from the shaft end, forward is clockwise and reverse anticlockwise.

Comment: Thanks a lot though I have an extra question here, where is the end of shaft? you mean where commutator is placed or the other side of which there is no commutator?

Comment: The 'shaft end' is the side  on which the shaft protrudes, for coupling to the load.

Comment: Thank you sooo much